# Convert NSAttributedString to HTML String

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsattributedstring

I want Only Body Part from HTML String.

Below code is Full HTLM String:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css">
<title></title>
<meta name="Generator" content="Cocoa HTML Writer">
<style type="text/css">
p.p1 {margin: 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px; line-height: 45.0px; font: 37.9px 'Times New Roman'; color: #000000; -webkit-text-stroke: #000000}
span.s1 {font-family: 'Times New Roman'; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 37.92pt; font-kerning: none}
span.s2 {font-family: 'TimesNewRomanPS-BoldMT'; font-weight: bold; font-style: normal; font-size: 37.92pt; font-kerning: none}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<p class="p1"><span class="s1">-1 Water damage and dry-rot observed on fascia boards around </span><span class="s2">the perimeter of the structur</span><span class="s1">e.</span></p>
</body>
</html>
```

I want Only Below Part Without CSS.

```
<body>
<p class="p1"><span class="s1">-1 Water damage and dry-rot observed on fascia boards around </span><span class="s2">the perimeter of the structur</span><span class="s1">e.</span></p>
</body>
```

Comment: If you don't import the class definition `<style ... span.s1 {...}</style>` you might get strange result, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used webView instead of textView to display attributed string.

```
NSString *strState = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.innerHTML"];
```

This method will return to you HTML string without CSS.

Answer (score 0):

```
 NSString * string;
 NSString * pattern;

 string = html// [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[[NSBundle mainBundle]  URLForResource:@"File" withExtension:nil] encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:nil];
 pattern = @"<body>[ \\w\\d\\n<>=\\\"-/]*</body>";

 NSRegularExpression *   regex =  [[NSRegularExpression alloc]initWithPattern:pattern options:(NSRegularExpressionAnchorsMatchLines) error:nil] ;
 NSTextCheckingResult * result = [regex firstMatchInString:string options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, string.length)];
  if (result != nil){
     NSString * resultString  = [string substringWithRange: result.range];
     NSLog(resultString);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

On mac, if you still want to have styles, but want to have them embedded in your tags, you can ask NSAttributedString to exclude style tags like this :

```
NSDictionary *documentAttributes = @{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType,
                                     NSExcludedElementsDocumentAttribute: @[@"style"]
                                     };
NSData *htmlData = [attributedString dataFromRange:NSMakeRange(0, attributedString.length) documentAttributes:documentAttributes error:NULL];
```

In this way, you will have all the styles embedded in your tags.

Unfortunately it's not available on iOS.